# Ruby pack and Latin (high-ASCII) characters

Tags: ruby, utf-8, pack

An action outputs a fixed-length string via Ruby's pack function

```
clean = [edc_unico,  sequenza_sede, cliente_id.to_s, nome, indirizzo, cap,  comune, provincia, persona, note, telefono,  email]
string  = clean.pack('A15A5A6A40A35A5A30A2A40A40A18A25')
```

However, the data is in UTF-8 as to allow latin/high-ascii characters.  The result of the pack action is logical. high-ascii characters take the space of 2 regular ascii characters. The resulting string is shortened by 1 space character, defeating the original purpose.

What would be a concise ruby command to interpret high-ascii characters and thus add an extra space at the end of each variable for each high-ascii character, so that the length can be brought to its proper target?  (note: I am assuming there is no directive that addresses this specifically, and the whole lot of pack directives is mind-muddling)

**update**  an example where the second line shifts positions based on accented characters

```
CNFrigo                                         539                                     Via Privata Da Via Iseo 6C                                            20098San Giuliano Milanese         MI02 98282410                         02 98287686       12886480156     12886480156 Bo3                 Euro                Giuseppe Frigo Transport 349 2803433                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   M.Gianoli@Delanchy.Fr S.Galliard@Delanchy.Fr      
CNIn's M                                        497                                     Via Istituto S.Maria della Pietà,                                    30173Venezia                       Ve041 8690111       340 6311408       0041 5136113      00115180283     02896940273 B60Fm               Euro                Per Documentazioni Tecniche Inviare Materiale A : Silvia_Scarpa@Insmercato.It Amministrazione : Michela_Bianco@Insmercato.It Silvia Scarpa Per Liberatorie 041/5136171 Sig.Ra Bianco Per Pagamento Fatture 041/5136111 (Solo Il Giovedi Pomeriggio Dalle 14 All                                        Beniservizi.Insmercato@Pec.Gruppopam.It
```

Comment: Do you have an example of `clean` array?

Comment: question updated above

Comment: "High-ASCII," like "extended ASCII," is an imprecise term that adds more confusion to your question than it does clarity. If you want to refer to characters that are represented by more than one byte in UTF-8, a good term to use is "multi-byte UTF-8 character."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use `pack` to format strings to fixed width columns for display. That’s not what it’s for, it is generally used for packing data into fixed *byte* structures for things like network protocols.

You probably want to use a format string instead, which is better suited for manipulating data for display.

Have a look at [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-25) (i.e. the `%` method on string). Like `pack` it uses another little language which is defined in [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Taking a simplified example, with the two arrays:

```
plain = ["Iseo", "Next field"]
accent = ["Pietà", "Next field"]
```

then using `pack` like this:

```
puts plain.pack("A10A10")
puts accent.pack("A10A10")
```

will produce a result that looks like this, where “Next field” isn’t aligned since `pack` is dealing with the *width in bytes*, not the *displayed width*:

```
Iseo      Next field
Pietà    Next field
```

Using a format string, like this:

```
puts "%-10s%-10s" % plain
puts "%-10s%-10s" % accent
```

produces the desired result, since it is dealing with the displayable width:

```
Iseo      Next field
Pietà     Next field
```